# Accessing Data in Listbox columns not displayed

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a ListBox with several columns of data. I want to display 6 columns of data and populate hidden textboxes with other data in order to reference for other call.

The information is a SQL statement stored in the rowsource of my listbox.

```
SELECT TBLactionstaken.ProcessedDate, TBLreasons.Description, 
TBLactionstaken.MANHType, TBLactionstaken.ActionStatus,
TBLactionstaken.ReceiptDate, TBLactionstaken.LetterTo, 
TBLactionstaken.ActionTakenID, TBLactionstaken.TranProcDate, 
TBLactionstaken.RecordNumber, TBLactionstaken.ActionDate, 
TBLreasons.ReasonID FROM TBLreasons 
RIGHT JOIN TBLactionstaken ON 
TBLreasons.ReasonID = TBLactionstaken.ReasonID 
WHERE (((TBLactionstaken.ActionStatus)="Processed" Or (TBLactionstaken.ActionStatus)="Received" Or (TBLactionstaken.ActionStatus)="Printed by PS") 
AND ((TBLactionstaken.TranProcDate) Is Null) 
AND ((TBLactionstaken.RecordNumber)=[Forms]![frmParticipant]![txtRecordNumber]) AND ((TBLactionstaken.ActionDate)>=Now()-180) 
AND ((TBLreasons.ReasonID)=20 Or (TBLreasons.ReasonID)=21 Or (TBLreasons.ReasonID)=22 Or (TBLreasons.ReasonID)=36 Or (TBLreasons.ReasonID)=38 Or (TBLreasons.ReasonID)=42 Or (TBLreasons.ReasonID)=34)) 
ORDER BY TBLactionstaken.ActionTakenID DESC;
```

The first 6 items in the select will be the columns of my listbox, the other items I would like to reference in my textboxes. I am able to pull the items displayed in VBA with:

```
 txtDesc = [lstAssignTransactions].[Column](1)         
 txtReasonDesc = [lstAssignTransactions].[Column](4)  
 txtReasonID = [lstAssignTransactions].[Column](3)
```

How do I reference the information not displayed. I did try to utilize:

```
txtActionID = [lstAssignTransactions].[Column](7)
```

because this information would technically be the 7th column, but no luck.

Comment: Column index begins with 0 so 7th column is index 6. Do you have ColumnCount and ColumnWidths set to correspond with number of fields in SQL?

Comment: Are you saving this other related info to fields in another table? That would be duplicating data. VBA is not needed to just display this info. Expression in textbox ControlSource can accomplish.

Comment: I'm not saving it no, I just need the reference number to pull additional data into the form. I do have column widths and column count set. column count is 6 and the widths vary based on the information in the field

Comment: You have 11 fields in query so ColumnCount should be 11 in order for referencing all columns to work properly. Defining column widths for each is not so critical.